# Forwarded email to another recipient DeliveredTo me

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I tried to forward an email that landed in my Gmail account to a 3rd party (through the Gmail web interface); should be simple enough...

However, I check my own emails immediately afterwards, and I had received the forwarded email, back in my Gmail account.

The headers of this email are something like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.68.212.3 with HTTP; Fri, 25 May 2012 03:20:14 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <201205250719.q4P7JjHn009297@ast-m01.mail.aol.com>
References: <201205250719.q4P7JjHn009297@ast-m01.mail.aol.com>
Date: Fri, 25 May 2012 11:20:14 +0100
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CAGkfXuiZKGY9qut7Wu1m7F6pPLmoG9AbcvY3h6bfLLE+PQauSg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Fwd: AOL Postmaster Support Request #97257 Update
From: Me <me@gmail.com>
To: target@example.com
```

I'm puzzled.. the Delivered To header presumably means that the email was delivered to me (which it was) but why? The To header correctly shows my target.

Did I automatically get a copy of the email? Or have I (only) received the mail?

I tried forwarding the email on to another account of mine. I received the forwarded email in the target account, but also received a copy back in my Gmail account.

Not sure why I get the unnecessary copy sent back to me, nor how to stop it.

I normally use Gmail through a client (Outlook/Thunderbird); I'll try forwarding via the client and see what happens.

Comment: The copy of email you receive is marked a "read" or "unread" by default?

Comment: It was unread, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this all makes sense is that target@example.com has a setting which says "Forward all incoming mails to me@gmail.com"

One another possibility is that your message was not delivered and you received a new message in the same tread saying, "Message Delivery Failed" but you have not noticed that until now.

Comment: There definitely isn't a forwarding applied to the target email account. And the mail is categorically not a Message Delivery Failed one. I agree, these would make sense. As I said in the OP, I re-forwarded the same email to a different address and the same thing happened - both myself and the target received the email.

Comment: @CJM did you check your filters though to make sure you have nothing that would be sending your email to yourself again when you forward.

Comment: There are absolutely no filters/forwarding or other embellishments set up on either the sending or receiving accounts. It's baffling.