# determine recipient email address in gmail in case of forwarding

Tags: email, gmail, email-forwarding

I have two email accounts. One on Gmail, other provided by my workplace. I have set up email-forwarding on my workplace account to receive them in Gmail as well.

Sometimes, I receive an email but I am not able to determine which account it was delivered to. In the "to: " row of email details, I do not see any of email accounts listed there.

Comment: Related: [Forwarded email to another recipient DeliveredTo me](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27279/88163)

Answer (score 1):

As I typed my question, I discovered the solution. Simply click on the "three dot" options button on the right of your email and click on "Show original". (It is like source code of your email.) Now search for "Delivered-To:" field and find the email address you were looking for.